# Поиск по enum. Java

Tags: java, enum

Всем привет! У меня есть два Enum. В одном написана стоимость, в другом предмет. Название у них одинаковы. Как можно сделать поиск по Enum и найти стоимость и предмет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Находим Days по значению AnotherEnum и выводим цену:

```java
    enum Days {
        TOMORROW{
            @Override
            public int getPrice() {
                return 200;
            }
        }, YESTERDAY{
            @Override
            public int getPrice() {
                return 100;
            }
        };

        public abstract int getPrice();
    }

    enum AnotherEnum {
        TOMORROW, YESTERDAY;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnotherEnum val = AnotherEnum.YESTERDAY;
        Optional<Days> optionalValue = Arrays.stream(Days.values()).filter(d -> d.name().equals(val.name()) ).findFirst();
        System.out.println(optionalValue.isPresent()?optionalValue.get().getPrice():"500 Internal Server Error");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Например как-то так (код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)). Будет работать при условии полного совпадения имён и порядка объявления в enum-ах:

```
enum class FirstEnum(val value: Int) {
    ONE(1), TWO(2)
}

enum class SecondEnum(val thing: String) {
    ONE("thing0"), TWO("thing1")
}

fun searchInEnums(query: String): Pair<Int, String>? =
    FirstEnum.values().mapIndexed { index, value -> value to SecondEnum.values()[index] }
        .firstOrNull { it.first.name == query }
        ?.let { it.first.value to it.second.thing }
```

Comment: а не котлин есть?

Comment: @ПавелВороник, там тоже самое будет. Только первую строку на цикл заменить, вторую тоже. Ну и вручную конструктор Pair вызывать. И реализовать его, если его в яве нет. Возможно, первые две строки можно даже почти не меняя на стримах сделать. Но тут уже я не силён, боюсь в синтаксисе ошибиться)